# What does #pragma intrinsic mean?

Tags: c, assembly

Just want to know what does #pragma intrinsic(_m_prefetchw) mean ?

Comment: It means nothing, _m_prefetchw is already an intrinsic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, that looks like someone was intending to modify some MSVC++ specific setting. However, that setting is not a valid option for the [intrinsic pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43.aspx). [_m_prefetchw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1c04w60.aspx) on the other hand is a 3D Now! intrinsic function.

Like all compiler intrinsic functions, it exposes (possibly) faster assembly instructions supported by the underlying hardware to your C or C++ application in a manner

A. more consistent with optimizers, and
B. more consistent with the language, when compared with using inline assembly.

On MSVC on x86_64/x64/amd64 systems, inline assembly is not supported, so one must use such intrinsics to access whizzbang features of the underlying hardware.

Finally, it should be noted that [_m_prefetchw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1c04w60.aspx) is a 3D Now! intrinsic, and 3D Now! is only supported on AMD hardware. It's probably not something you want to use for new code (i.e. you should use SSE instead, which works on both Intel and AMD hardware, and has more features to boot).

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of "#pragma intrinsic" (note spelling), as with all "#pragma" directives, varies from one compiler to another.  Generally, it indicates that a particular thing that looks syntactically like a call to an external function should be replaced with some inline code.  In some cases, this may greatly improve performance, especially if the compiler can determine constant values for some or all of the arguments (in the latter situation, the compiler may be able to compute the value of the function and replace it with a constant).

Generally, having functions processed as intrinsic won't pose any particular problem.  The biggest danger is that if a user defines in one module a function with the same name as one of the compiler's intrinsic function, and attempts to call that function from another module, the compiler might instead replace the function call with its expected instruction sequence.  To prevent this, some compilers don't enable intrinsic functions by default (since doing so would cause the above incompatibility with some standard-conforming programs) but provide #pragma directives to do enable them.  Compilers may also use command-line option to enable intrinsics (since the standard allows anything there), or may define some functions like __memcpy() as intrinsic, and within string.h, use a #define directive to convert memcpy into __memcpy (since programs that #include string.h are not allowed to use memcpy for any other purpose).

Answer (score 2):

In `C`, it depends on whether the implementation recognizes (and defines) it.

If the implementation does not recognize the "intrinsic" preprocessing token, the pragma is ignored.
If the implementation recognizes it, whatever is defined will happen (and if another implementation defines it differently, a different thing happens on the other implementation).

So, check the documentation for the implementation you're talking about (*edit: and don't use it if you expect to compile your source on different implementations*).

<sub>*I couldn't find any reference to "#pragma intrinsic" in `man gcc`, on my system.*</sub>

Comment: Well, that would make sense, given that it's not a GCC option. I don't have `__declspec` in my GCC manual either -- I don't see what that has to do with the question. There are lots of compilers in the world other than GCC. The rest of the answer is okay though.

Comment: Those are indeed MSVC specific pragmas.

Comment: The C Standard (question is tagged C) explicitly defines what happens for `#pragma WHATEVER`. Since the OP doesn't say what is his current implementation, I assumed he wanted the meaning from the Standard.

Comment: @pmg: Which is why the first part of your answer is correct. I don't see why GCC gets involved here at all though (after all, it does plenty of nonstandard (but potentially useful)) things.

Comment: @Billy: again it was the OP not providing full details that prompted me to add the gcc info. If he uses gcc (the same version as me) the implementation does not describe the `intrinsic` #pragma.

Answer (score 1):

The intrinsic pragma tells the compiler that a function has known behavior. The compiler may call the function and not replace the function call with inline instructions, if it will result in better performance.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It looks like an accurate quote of the documentation? Maybe it is downvoted for not being specific enough?